# JavaScript String with quotas or comma

Tags: javascript

I have a js String with `'` or `"` inside.
as a result my code execution stops with: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`.
Happens in chrome and IE.
String example:

```
XfÍ­Ë`á­²Û)a^ËoT%çíZ
óAuGÒH¾CnäjIònh²~æuÁ8>ÊMï|xWwJ¨L
´³á×ß1Q/;©îé*g®ûA4PÆÎhÂ&V§Fà
#+ûsÙ9
8g¬dJ
```

fiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/dvysedp9/).

I dont want to change the String in any way like [rite-a-string-containing-commas-and-double-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46637955/write-a-string-containing-commas-and-double-quotes-to-csv).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to solve `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` is it was not clear.

Comment: it looks like you have multiple lines and you can't have multiple lines in a JS string like that.

Comment: Without altering your string, there are exactly 3 ways to create strings in JavaScript: `\``, `'` and `"`. Last two wont work because the string is multiline, and the first one won't work because the symbol is inside the string and you do not want to escape it. You could alternatively read the string from some file.

Comment: @DanielA.White - and remove `enter` or `\n` in the backend will do the trick?

Comment: Where is your string? Directly in your JS source code? Or are you sending it from a script (say, PHP)? If the former, you can just escape the offending characters (you'll also have to replace the newlines). Be aware that you may end up with encoding issues for what looks like binary code if you haven't kept a consistent encoding/charset while manipulating it.

Comment: you might be able to use a JSON encoder that will handle all the special cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ES6 String Template](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/template_strings)

```
let data = `#+ûsÙ9'"`
console.log(data) // #+ûsÙ9'"
```

Answer (score 1):

If the line breaks are part of your string value, you need to use \n. In .js file, you can't treat .js like a regular 'text editor' with that 'visual' representation.

```js
var t = "\nXfÍ­Ë`á­²Û)a^ËoT%çíZ\nóAuGÒH¾CnäjIònh²~æuÁ8>ÊMï|xWwJ¨L\n´³á×ß1Q/;©îé*g®ûA4PÆÎhÂ&V§Fà\n#+ûsÙ9\n8g¬dJ"

console.log( t );
```

Hope it helps!